# How do I provide the component that is replacing <slot> with properties?

Tags: vue.js

I have a component that functions as a basis for other components.

```
//The Basis Component lets call it slotComponent
<template>
   <div>
     //somestuff 
     <slot :someProperties="someLocalValues"></slot>
   </div>
</template>
```

As you can see I want to give the component that is replacing the slot some Properties that only this component will know.

However if I do this:

```
 //Some page Component lets call it mainPage
 <template>   
   <slotComponent>
       <someOtherComponent/>
   </slotComponent>
 </template>
```

Then "someOtherComponent" will not have access to "someProperties". How can I provide this component with said property?

Note that someLocalValues are defined in the scope of slotComponent and not its parent. So I cant provide said information in the mainPage.

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify the `v-slot` directive in order to bind the props. Check the documentation here: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-slots.html#Scoped-Slots

You also will need to pass the props to your child component.

In your example, you would need to do something like:

```html
 <template>   
   <slotComponent>
       <someOtherComponent v-slot="slotData" :data="slotData.someProperties"/>
   </slotComponent>
 </template>
```

This is the same, but with an additional `<template>` for clarity:

```html
 <template>   
   <slotComponent>
       <template v-slot="slotData">
         <someOtherComponent :data="slotData.someProperties"/>
       </template>   
   </slotComponent>
 </template>
```

Comment: That requires me to define slotData in the mainPage, correct? Or can I say slotData = {} and someOtherComponent understand to get someProperties because it was provided inside of the slotComponent?

Comment: @telion No, `slotData` is just a name you give to the bound data from the slot. You can name it however you want, it is defined in the `v-slot` directive; you do not need to define it anywhere else.